# Adding Multiple Items XCUITest TextField in a Loop

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

In XCUITest in Xcode how can I add several records using the interface. I have 2-3 records that I need to enter through the UITest, so I am running a loop. It runs the app but then the loop messes things up and sometimes the XCUITest automation is not finished and loop is fast so it does not enter correct text or does not remove or delete text after inserting.

```
 let rows: NSArray = (userInfo?["DataTable"]) as! NSArray

                let taskTextField = XCUIApplication().textFields["taskTextField"]

                for index in 1...rows.count {

                    let taskName = (rows[index] as! NSArray)[0] as! String
                    taskTextField.tap()
                    taskTextField.typeText(taskName + "\n")

                    XCUIApplication().buttons["addTaskButton"].tap()

                    taskTextField.tap()

                    let deleteString = String(repeating: XCUIKeyboardKey.delete.rawValue, count: taskName.count)

                    // clear the textfield
                    taskTextField.typeText(deleteString)
                }
```

Any idea how can I slow down the loop or maybe use a different technique to insert multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

You should try asserting (`XCTAssertEqual(taskTextField.value, ...`), waiting for the results of each cycle (`waitForExistence()`), or simply use `sleep(1)`